# How to clear EPERM : operation not permitted warning while installing gulp

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm trying to install gulp in Windows8 by issuing the below command,

```
C:\Users\acer>npm install gulp -g

C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp-> C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\gulp\node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ gulp@4.0.0
updated 1 package in 63.384s
```

Although the installation was successful, while executing the gulp I'm receiving the below error.

```
C:\Users\acer>gulp -v
'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can someone help to overcome this issue?.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `npm` global directory to your `PATH` variable. You can do this by executing the below command.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME_OR_LOGIN\AppData\Roaming\npm;
```

After issuing the above command, try executing `gulp -v` and it will work.

Hope this helps!